# PHP LIKE is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have got this PHP code

```
$search=$_GET['Searchusername'];
$searchuser="SELECT fullname,lastname,userName FROM users WHERE userName LIKE '%{$search}%' 
OR fullname LIKE '%{$search}%' OR LIKE '%{$search}%'";

$query = mysqli_query($link, $searchuser);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
```

But it gives me 2 errors

```
mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
```

And

```
mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
```

And i want it to work with LIKE operator.

Comment: Your query fails, and `$query` becomes `false`. You cannot get data from it. You need to check if `$query` is false - output mysql error. Then, you will understand that your query is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstoff, `LIKE` is part of SQL syntax, not PHP. In your query you are missing a column name, which is why it is failing:

```
$searchuser="SELECT fullname,lastname,userName 
             FROM users 
             WHERE userName LIKE '%{$search}%' 
             OR fullname LIKE '%{$search}%' 
             OR lastname LIKE '%{$search}%'";
```

The boolean you're getting is `false` because the query failed due to `lastname` being missing.